# The problem when using Double buffering Bitmap with AlphaBlend

Tags: c++, winapi

My text is overlapped when it change.

but it's time text so always changing

i already tried

---

TranslateBlt(memhdc, TextBoxRect.left, TextBoxRect.top, TextBoxRect.right, TextBoxRect.bottom, hdc, TextBoxRect.right, TextBoxRect.bottom, RGB(0,0,0));

case WM_ERASEBKGND:
return true;

InvalidateRect(NULL, &TextBoxRect, TRUE);

---

here is my code.

---

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
HDC memhdc;
HBITMAP bgbitmap, oldbitmap;

stringstream stream;
int cur = delay / 10;
stream << "Ms : " << msec;
wchar_t str[120];
mbstowcs_s(NULL, str, 120, stream.str().c_str(), 120);

memhdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
bgbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, TextBoxRect.right, TextBoxRect.bottom);
oldbitmap = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(memhdc, bgbitmap);

BLENDFUNCTION bf;
bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
bf.BlendFlags = 0;
bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
bf.AlphaFormat = 0;

AlphaBlend(memhdc, TextBoxRect.left, TextBoxRect.top, TextBoxRect.right, TextBoxRect.bottom, hdc, TextBoxRect.left, TextBoxRect.top, TextBoxRect.right, TextBoxRect.bottom, bf);
SetBkMode(memhdc, TRANSPARENT);
SetTextColor(memhdc, RGB(255, 0, 0));
DrawText(memhdc, str, -1, &TextBoxRect, DT_LEFT | DT_NOCLIP);

BitBlt(hdc, TextBoxRect.left, TextBoxRect.top, TextBoxRect.right, TextBoxRect.bottom, memhdc, TextBoxRect.left, TextBoxRect.top, SRCCOPY);

DeleteObject(SelectObject(memhdc,oldbitmap));
DeleteObject(bgbitmap);
DeleteDC(memhdc);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
```

Comment: Draw your text with a solid background (`OPAQUE` rather than `TRANSPARENT`), or use `BitBlt` to restore the original part of the off-screen bitmap before you render the text over it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're ready to draw transparent digital changes.

You can try to call `InvalidateRect` and `UpdateWindow` to refresh the local area at the same time, because the system regards the drawing operation in the window as a low priority operation, which can be redrawn immediately with UpdateWindow.

Also you can try the following code, as Jonathan Potter says

Just like :

```
   AlphaBlend(memhdc, TextBoxRect.left, TextBoxRect.top, TextBoxRect.right,       TextBoxRect.bottom, hdc, TextBoxRect.left, TextBoxRect.top, TextBoxRect.right, TextBoxRect.bottom, bf);
   SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
   SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255, 0, 0));       
   BitBlt(hdc, TextBoxRect.left, TextBoxRect.top, TextBoxRect.right, TextBoxRect.bottom, hdc, TextBoxRect.left, TextBoxRect.top, SRCCOPY);
   DrawText(hdc, str, -1, &TextBoxRect, DT_LEFT | DT_NOCLIP);
```